How to properly punctuate "for all" after mathematical expressions?
One thing about mathematical writing that has always puzzled me is how to properly punctuate "for all" after a mathematical expression. Let me give you an example.

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is called increasing if $$f(x)>f(y), \text{ for all } x>y.$$

Does the comma after the inequality and before "for all" belong there? Initially, I thought that it did because in my native language that would be the way to go. However, I noticed that many (I think in fact most) people would write this as

$$f(x)>f(y) \text{ for all } x>y.$$

I believe that probably both ways work since I have seen native speakers using both of these constructions, but I wonder which one is preferable and what would be the best way to go if you write a paper.

May be it is better be written as: x > y => f(x) > f(y)

They read equally well to a native English speaker. There are rules about commas but most people ignore them (or don’t know them). I could have put commas in both above sentences, after well and commas, and even to replace the parentheses, and it would read the same to most people.

They are part of the same clause so no comma should be used.

@CyclotomicField thank you for your comment, this is precisely what puzzled me: whether the "for all $x>y$" part is part of the same clause or whether it is a parenthetical remark. I could see arguments in favour of both, but I was not quite sure and this is why I decided to ask this question here.

@JustAnAmateur you can tell it's not two clauses because "for all $x > y$" doesn't have both a subject and predicate. A parenthetical remark can always be removed without loss of meaning but it's necessary in this context so it's also not a parenthetical remark.

No, that comma does not belong there, for precisely the reason given by CyclotomicField. That said, puncutation rules in natural language are quite flexible, and if that part before the "for all x>y" was really long, then it might be acceptable to insert a comma there as a pause. In any case, this is better than your suggestion: for each x and each y,  x > y ⟹ f(x) > f(y).
